# Echo a variable in email form

Tags: php, email

I want to know why the partsname and qty don't echo inside an email message body.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    include('../config.php');
    $roomid = $_POST['roomid'];
    $status=$_POST['status'];
    $tc=$_POST['transactioncode'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE athan_orders SET status='$status' WHERE id='$roomid'");
    header("location: viewords.php");

    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM athan_members where id='$roomid'");
    $recepient=$_POST['id'];
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orderdetails where transactioncode = '$tc'");
    $partsname=$_POST['partsname'];
    $qty=$_POST['qty'];
        $to = "$recepient"; //enter the recipients email address here
        $subject = "Order Confirmed"; //email subject
        $message = "
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Order Confirmed</title>
        </head> 
        <body>
        <p>Your Order at Athan Motorcycles has been confirmed by the admin. Please contact the company for the details and verification of your order.</p>
        <table>
                  <tr >
                    <td><div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Products</div></td>
                    <td>Qty</td>
                  </tr>
        </table>
                  <tr>
                  <td>"echo "$partsname"";
                  <td>"echo "$qty"";
                  </td>
                  </td>
                  </tr>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Thank you!</th>
        <th>-Athan Motorcycles</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>
        ";
        // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
        // More headers
        $fromemail = "melvin.napoles@yahoo.com"; //enter senders email address here
        $headers .= "From: <". $fromemail . ">\r\n";
        //$ccemail = ""; //cc email address
        //$headers .= "Cc: $ccemail" . "\r\n";
        if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) == TRUE){
        print "Success!";
        }else{
        print "Error!";
        }


?>
```

so i query the parts name and qty from the order details and make a variable to them. then i inserted it inside the email form. Is it correct or there is something wrong from calling the variables?

Comment: Is there a problem? Or do you just want a syntax check? That's not really on-topic here. Just eyeballing it, though, you have all sorts of syntax errors with your use of `echo` when you build `$message`.

Comment: yes sir there is a problem when i try to simulate it the partsname and qty is not listing down in the email sent to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No its not correct, you can't use echo inside variable. Use this to concenate variables:

```
    $message = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Order Confirmed</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <p>Your Order at Athan Motorcycles has been confirmed by the admin. Please contact the company for the details and verification of your order.</p>
    <table>
              <tr >
                <td><div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Products</div></td>
                <td>Qty</td>
              </tr>
    </table>
              <tr>
              <td>$partsname 
              <td>$qty
              </td>
              </td>
              </tr>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Thank you!</th>
    <th>-Athan Motorcycles</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";
```

Answer (score 1):

When concatenating a string you do not use the echo command; you use a period to connect them.

Also, echo and print are very similar, but echo allows you to output multiple strings while print only outputs one.  So, you should change your print functions to echo instead, and as a general idea just use echo instead of print.

But, to fix the concatenation of strings, change these lines:

```
<td>"echo "$partsname"";
<td>"echo "$qty"";
```

To this:

```
<td>".$partsname."
<td>".$qty."
```

Comment: There is no problem with the use of `print` here. Also, I'm pretty sure OP doesn't actually want to output the semicolons.